# EJS include as wrapper

Tags: node.js, ejs

Can I include another `.ejs` file that will wrap the current content?

I want to have a general layout like this:
layout.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
    <!-- I want to "inject" my code here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to use this template from another file, like this:
content.ejs

```
<% inside(layout) ? { %>
<a href="">content</a>
<% } %>
```

Can I do something like this?

I'm currently doing this the other way around, I call layout with a parameter `include_name` but it's a little inconvenient. I would like to call the relevant `content.ejs` which includes the generic content itself. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Here is pattern that simulates that https://github.com/dheeraj-br/ejs_layout_implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [EJS Documentation](https://github.com/mde/ejs#layouts):

> EJS does not specifically support blocks, but layouts can be
>   implemented by including headers and footers, like so:
>
> ```
> <%- include('header') -%>
> <h1>
>   Title
> </h1>
> <p>
>   My page
> </p>
> <%- include('footer') -%>
> ```

Although some frameworks have some facilities to deal with problem. for example [**Express**](http://expressjs.com/) until version 3.x had layout support and for latest versions you could use it as a stand alone npm package: [express-partials](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials)

With this package in place you define a `<%- body %>` region in your skeleton template (*layout.ejs*) and when you call your desired layout (*content.ejs*), express will render *layout.ejs* with *content.ejs* as `<%- body %>` ( unless you set `{layout:false}` which then it only renders *content.ejs*):

layout.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content">
      <%- body %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.ejs

```
<a href="">content</a>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , partials = require('express-partials')
  , app = express();

// load the express-partials middleware
app.use(partials());

app.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.render('content.ejs') 
  // -> render layout.ejs with content.ejs as `body`.
})

app.listen(3000);
```